# Escaping double quotes in TF2 scripting

Tags: scripting, console, escaping, source-engine

In [TF2 scripting](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Scripting), there is a simple command, `echo`. This simply logs a message to the console. It can be used with or without double quotes. However, I want to be able to log something to the console involving double quotes--say, the string `He said, "nope."`. In conventional programming, one would escape the quotes, as so:

```
echo "He said, \"nope.\""
```

However, in the TF2 console, this writes:

```
He said, \ nope.\
```

Is there a way to use quotes in `echo` and related commands? (E.g. `say`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to output double quotes using `echo` or `say`, only single quotes. ([source](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Scripting#Echo)) (In fact whenever you type double quotes into regular chat they're automatically changed into single quotes. I don't know why this limitation exists, I'd have to dig around.)

Comment: Is there no hack, like a variable or something?

Comment: As far as I'm aware `echo` can't echo the contents of a convar so no.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old thread, but in case anyone else is trying to find a fix for this and found this post, let me provide an example of how to use single quotes. I had an alias for switching crosshairs, as such:

> alias "default" "cl_crosshair_blue 255; cl_crosshair_red 255; cl_crosshair_green 0; cl_crosshair_file "" "

This is to change the color of my crosshair, but more importantly, reset my crosshair to the "None" in options, letting the crosshair change depending on weapon, as I like most of the default crosshairs- but it would fail at the quotation mark immediately after "file", simply changing the colors and nothing more.

Using single quotes fixes this. Using ALT+0145 and ALT+0146 gives you the starting and ending single quotes (respectively) that you need. Replacing those two double quotes after "file" with the single quotes made the command work as intended.

> alias "default" "cl_crosshair_blue 255; cl_crosshair_red 255; cl_crosshair_green 0; cl_crosshair_file ‘’ "

So anytime you absolutely *need* to use a set quotation marks twice in a command, just use single quotes.